# Average values; FOR loops

Tags: for-loop, average, moving-average

If I have a 5x5 matrix called MATRIX1 like this:

12  13  14  15  16

21  23  24  25  26

31  43  52  23  43

63  36  74  47  45

21  23  32  34  43

How can I make a for loop (or something similar) which will give me a new matrix with average values of all columns of 5x5 matrix?

I mean to get another matrix with a name MATRIX2 in which will be just one row with 5 average values of each column from MATRIX1.

Thanks

Comment: what language you are targetting?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, it's expected that you attempt to code this yourself. I would suggest you do some research on your issue (maybe try the search box at the top of the page) and make an attempt at writing some code yourself. If/when you come across any issues with your code ask again and explain what you have tried, and why it did not work for you. See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help with asking a great question as well as [Minimum, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to declare an array of size 5 like this

> int a[] = new int[5];

Second you need to go through all col values and calculate it's average

```
for(int i=0;i<5;++i){
   int sum = 0;
   for(int j=0;j<5;++j){
        sum+=a[j][i];
   }
   a[i] = sum ;
}
```

i assumed you use java as u didn't tell what lang you use

Comment: Sorry that I didn't provide a language :(  I am using Matlab

Comment: try to do the same algo in Matlab ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example of matrix in Excel [MATRIX in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9T6Q8.jpg) . . . But to calculate this in Matlab is already challenge for me.